# Could not find method implementation() for arguments

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, andengine

I try to run my app, but gradle doesn`t want to compose it.

Can you tell me what should I do ?

> Error:(36, 0) Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.6.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

My app build.gradle file

```
 minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.6.2'
    compile project(':AndEngine')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.8.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.4'

}
```

Comment: You have to use the plugin 3.x.x to use the implementation DSL

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti thanks, I was not careful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.6.2'
```

with

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.6.2'
```

You need to update your gradle version in order to use `implementation`.
You can do that updating your buildscript block in your project build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

`compile` has been deprecated and it will be no longer supported in future gradle releases.

So to let your project compile just change that line as I suggested, but consider to update your gradle version and use `implementation` for all your dependencies.

**UPDATE**

You should use the same version for all the modules of your firebase dependencies.

So you could need to update your app build.gradle this way

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.6.2'
    compile project(':AndEngine')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.8.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.2'
}
```

Or you might have new build errors.

Also

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
```

is not the latest version and might bring new issues.

But I suggest to proceed step by step :)

**UPDATE 2**

If you declare a dependency for gson this way

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

You don't need

```
compile files('libs/gson-2.8.0.jar')
```

It is redundant and plus you can free your libs folder of a useless jar file

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. You are partially correct. Setup gradle sometimes can take a lot of time.

Comment: I find this answer a little bit confusing. Which build.gradle files should be changed? The update parts are not very clear regarding this information.

Comment: @Zerok, I've updated the answer. All the update parts refer the app build.gradle file. The one where you actually declare your dependencies.