# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies

Tags: android, build.gradle

actually i borrowed this project from someone and try to run it my own laptop but whenever i try build my project it show the following error

```
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of 
type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Comment: try this: `implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find method implementation() for arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744022/could-not-find-method-implementation-for-arguments)

Comment: i did what you say but it's not working