# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [...] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.depende

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle, zoom-sdk

I'm getting an error message while syncing the project with gradle. My error message is:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: 
Could not find method implementation() for arguments 
[DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':mobilertc'', configuration='default'}] on 
object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

My build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 29
   buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.CS.kba"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}



dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

}
```

I'm working on ingratiating zoom API to my app. I just did as the documentation said. The problem raised after I have added some modules and libraries as dependencies.

Comment: maybe similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744022/could-not-find-method-implementation-for-arguments ?